# Determine compiler in Matlab

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, mex

I would like to know if there is a way to determine which compiler Matlab is using. 
In my Matlab setup, I have two compilers that can be detected via `mex -setup` but I would like to know before I set it which one Matlab is currently using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mex.getCompilerConfigurations`:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/mex.getcompilerconfigurations.html